# How can I make a selectionSort in C++ function involving a class, and with an overload of operation < for an array?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, selection-sort

> I do not know how to how to call my operator< function into my selectionSort function.
> The selectionSort function is supposed to arrange the blog objects in the array from newest to oldest.
> The operator< function is comparing the days elapsed since the blog post of each blog.
> I could use some help on how to set up my selectionSort function which calls the operator< function.
>
> Errors include:
> -In function 'void selectionSort(Blog*, int)':
> -[Error] 'class Blog' has no member named 'operator<'
> -[Error] 'displayData' was not declared in this scope

```
void selectionSort(Blog blog[], int numBlogs)
{
    Blog temp;
    int minIndex=0;
    for (int i=0; i<numBlogs-1; i++)
    {
        minIndex = i;
        for (int j=i+1; j<numBlogs; j++)
        if (blog[j].operator<())
            minIndex=j;
                        //swap positions i and minIndex
        temp = blog[i];
        blog[i] = blog[minIndex];
        blog[minIndex] = temp;
        displayData(blog, numBlogs);
        
        
    }
}

    bool Blog::operator< (const Blog &right) const
        {
            if (daysElapsed() < right.daysElapsed())//comparing two objects that are in the blog[]
                return true;
           else
               return false;
        }
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] and the exact error message in [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63783486/edit).

Comment: OT: `if (cond) return true; else return false;` can be written smiply as `return cond;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of overloading an operator is so that you don't have to spell it out like a function call.

So for this line:

```
if (blog[j].operator<())
```

apart from the fact that you're missing the argument to `operator<`, you can just compare 2 `Blog` objects like this:

```
if (blog[j] < blog[i])
```

If you explicitly want to spell out the operator call, you could do:

```
if (blog[j].operator<(blog[i]))
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, it's missing an argument at least. And the `operator<` definition has `const` where needed.

Comment: Ah, yes. Should be a binary argument operator overload.

Comment: It can be a "unary" function if it's a member as it is in OP's code.

Comment: Well, calling `blog[j].operator<` looks clumsy.

Comment: Yes of course, operators are not meant to be used like that. (Though it works that way as well).